# Can you recommend me a dedicated server company that has fast servers?

Tags: dedicated-server

I currently pay $170 for my Quad Server. The transfer is unmonitored but the speed is really slow. Can you recommend me a couple of better alternatives, preferably with no setup fee?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ServerLoft - [got a quad core xeon](http://www.serverloft.com/dedizierte-server/server-details.php?products=0) with 4G RAM and 2x250Gb SATA Raid1 for $120 per month (including a Win2008 license - would be $20 less per month with linux).

http://www.serverloft.com

Great value for the money if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Signing up was *incredibly* painful and I've had one near-offensive support reply, but the support people do answer questions (*usually* without being offensive), pricing is fantastic, they offer full IPMI access to the server, and the transfer speed is excellent.

Comment: Hmm. In what way was signing up painful? The only odd thing I noticed was that they had to call me back on a land line to verify my phone number. Other than that it went really smooth; my server was up and running earlier than what they originally told me. I love the IPMP web interface thing; I have set up both that one _and_ the offsite monitoring thing (in their control panel) to send email notifications to my mobile phone if anything should go wrong with the server (or any component within it).

Comment: ...if you got a 'near offensive' support reply that may have to do with the fact that they're a German company. :) No offense intended to Germans, but all northern europeans (us Swedes included) can come across as rude to many other nationalities...  ...not sure why, but I guess it has to do with cultural/language differences or something...

Comment: I signed up, but then got a note saying they couldn't process my signup in the EU and could I sign up again from serverloft.com. I *had* signed up from serverloft.com! And then it wouldn't let me sign up because I was already in the system. It took a couple of days and several emails to get it sorted out. The support thing was beyond cultural diffs (I'm used to those), but has not been repeated on several further contacts. Been with them since Oct and I'm very pleased with the machine and the supports' been just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sales page for a host I used to work for as a sysadmin. They don't have anything that isn't fast: [NatNet Dedicated Servers](http://nationalnet.com/dedicated_hosting.html)

[Cyberwurx](http://cyberwurx.com/dedicated-overview.html) has pretty good hardware and better prices. Their support was always great (I am a former customer).

Comment: Thanks! I need something with 5-10TB of transfer on less than $170, though. Can you name me a couple of others?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at [iWeb](http://iweb.com/), personally. They're based in Montreal, and have really good facilities. Their unmetered plans are here: http://iweb.com/dedicated/unmetered-servers/.

10Mbps, Core2 DUO 2.4, 2GB, 320GB for $199 US a month (

They do colocating, too.

Disclaimer - I am an iWeb affliate (links on my blog, etc); the links posted are clean of any reference numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your 5-10TB/month at less than $170 requirement (in your comment on adric's answer) will be a challenge.

In the UK, I briefly had a server with [Tagadab](http://www.tagadab.com) (but don't get the wrong idea, it was only brief because I decided to host in the U.S. instead).  My experience was brief, but they did everything they said they would do (including near-instant setup), the server was very fast, transfer speeds were excellent, and they offer a terrific try-before-you-buy (the first week costs £1, literally). They claim "unlimited" data transfer.

I don't have any experience with these following links but ran across them the other day: [KoHvs](http://kohvs.com/) claim to offer unlimited transfer (with speed restrictions, but reasonable ones). [HiDefServers](http://www.hidefservers.com/organic_package.php) offers 100Mbit/sec up to 25TB for $179 (so close!).

Answer (score 0):

I use KoHvs and couldn't be happier with them.

[TechPain - KoHvs post](http://techpain.blogspot.com/2009/11/koh-virtual-servers-kohvscom.html)